# Business visit in Ireland followed by tourist visa in Netherlands

Tags: visas, schengen, ireland

I have an interview in Dublin, for which I am planning to take a short-stay business visa. After that I'm planning to go to Netherlands on a tourist visa (Schengen).

[INIS says](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Business%20Visa),

> ### Travel to-or-from Ireland via a different country
>
> Type or write a letter that describes your travel plan to-or-from Ireland if you intend to:
>
> - Travel to Ireland **directly from** a different country (ie not your home country or a country where you are a legal resident), or
> - Travel from Ireland **directly to** a different country
>
> The letter must also state if you need visas for those countries (or not). Include the letter with your application.
>
> If relevant, apply for those countries' visas before you apply for an Irish visa. Your application for an Irish visa may be refused if your passport does not contain the expected visas.
>
> If you do not get the expected visas before you apply for an Irish visa, explain why in your letter. The visa officer will include those reasons when reviewing your application.

Does this mean that I need to apply for the Dutch visa before the Irish visa? Wouldn't my Dutch visa application require that I already have an Irish visa? I'm a little confused on which to apply for first, and time is running out fast.

Answer (score 5):

The usual rule is to obtain visas in reverse order of your intended travel plan. In your case you need the Schengen Visa from the Netherlands first in order to demonstrate you can enter your next onward destination when you apply for your Irish visa.